# What are the options to drive Selenium2 (via WebDriver) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm setting up automated acceptance tests of a single page webapp.  I want to write test suite in JavaScript (or CoffeeScript). What are my options to *drive browsers and simulators using WebDriver compatible interface*, such as [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/), [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)?  I know of [selenium-webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) (aka WebDriverJs) and [webdriverjs](https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs).  Anything else available?  How do they compare maturity-wise and feature-wise?

Comment: Found a bit of argumentation here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/71

Comment: Protractor https://github.com/angular/protractor itself is a kind of option.  But when looking for WebDriver bindings, it essentially is WebDriverJs.

Comment: Is the Protractor thingie Angular specific? Hope you try it and can share the results :)

Comment: Angular specific? No. Angular oriented? Most definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been more or less successfully using this fork of webdriver (a bit more sugary): https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs and running it through node + mocha + chai stack, more or less like this: http://unexpectedliteral.com/2012/05/09/automated-functional-testing-with-javascript-using-mocha-and-selenium-part-2/

It has worked okayish I guess, at least haven't found out better alternatives. Should work against browserstack too I guess, actually that is something I'll try next.

Comment: Went with webdriverjs.  It really looks like there are no other bindings than the mentioned two.